# Link error for Windows functions

Tags: c, windows, linker, name-decoration

I'm trying to test if standard library (kernel32.dll) have one of the function.

Code snippet for test:

```
extern void CreateProcessA (void);
int
main (void)
{
  CreateProcessA ();
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and links as follow:

```
cl /c test.c
link test.obj kernel32.lib
```

This code can be compiled well with Visual C++, but cannot link:

```
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CreateProcessA referenced in function _main
```

But function CreateProcessA does exists in kernel32.dll, you no?

How to link it properly?

P.S. I don't want to run this code, just check that function exists (if code compiles and links - function exists).

Comment: But do you want to check if the function exists at compile time or at runtime? I don't see any use in the first one (heck, the documentation is there to be read, and anyway if you include windows.h if a function does not exist you end with a compilation error), while in the second case it may be useful since some functions are not available on every Windows version.

Answer (score 8):

To see if the function exists, you use

```
dumpbin /exports kernel32.dll | findstr CreateProcess
```

You didn't even use the right prototype, so of course the linker can't find the correct function. The naming convention is completely off, and CreateProcess is really a macro (that expands to either `CreateProcessA` or `W` depending on `UNICODE`).

(You don't need to link against `kernel32.lib` explicitly as that's already done by default by `cl.exe`)

Instead of declaring the prototype yourself, `#include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

Kernel32.dll exports the function as "CreateProcessA", note the missing leading underscore.  The only way to convince the linker to use that export is by linking kernel32.lib, an import library supplied by the Windows SDK.

You'll then run into the next problem, the import library declares the export as `_CreateProcess@40`.  This is a name decoration applied by the [__stdcall calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx).  That calling convention was explicitly designed to catch your mistake, you didn't declare the function properly.  The @40 part of the name indicates the number of bytes needed in the stack frame to pass the arguments.

So, to make it work you should `#include <windows.h>` to get the proper function declaration and link kernel32.lib to get the proper export name.

Comment: Not only that but the symbol is decorated further, prefixed with `__imp_`. So you also need a `__declspec(dllimport)` to get the right naming. But of course, that's done by `<windows.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are declaring your own version of CreateProcess(). Since you did not provide the body (code), the linker doesnt know where to check to find the function to execute.

In order to call CreateProcess from kernel32.lib, you need to include the proper headers

```
#include <windows.h>
```

If the compiler doesnt know windows.h then probably Platform SDK for windows isnt installed correctly.

you will also need to link with the proper lib

```
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")
```

You should also read the documentation about createprocess since it takes a gazillion of parametetrs

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  __inout_opt  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  __in         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  __in         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  __in_opt     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  __in         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  __out        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

You should search for CreateProcess examples across the interwebs and maybe consider switching to c++ since you're on windows

Answer (score 1):

For starters, put in a proper header file for the prototypes, `<windows.h>`, as this is a Windows source, add the *kernel32.lib* for your linker, remove that prototype as it is incorrect. Your `main` function is debatable as to whether you are creating a command line program or a windows program - if it is the latter, that should read '[WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx)'.

If you look in the MSDN for the function '[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx)', scroll down and you will see the 'Library', that is the hint to tell you which library you need to link for it to work properly.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Been wondering for some time how you were supposed to know what header and lib files to include and link with. Well, those MSDN pages are long and dull, and I rarely read to the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad idea, but if you want to do it, you need to link with the kernel32.lib export library.

Answer (score 0):

You must include `windows.h` in order to get the correct prototype:

```
#include <windows.h>
int
main (void)
{
  CreateProcess(); // will cause warning due to incorrect parameter list
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a particular reason you don't want to include `windows.h`?

Comment: But it's not C linkage in this case - CreateProcess uses stdcall which means that the name is decorated with the number of bytes of stack used for parameters - his declaration doesn't include it.

Comment: Wow! Larry is on Stack Overflow! Hi Larry!

Answer (score 0):

Using MinGW one can use the "-mwindows" flag. Example:

```
gcc.exe -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o newmain.c
gcc.exe -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hwprint_dll build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o -mwindows
```

This will include stuff like gdi32.a, kernel32.a, user32.a and ws2_32.a.